Using Gamma Ray Lasers to Blow Away Interstellar Medium
I'm working on a sci-fi project, and I'm designing a torchship that can go up to 0.3c. I wanted to use a whipple shield to prevent interstellar medium from damaging the ship, but then I came across this article:
Nuclear Processes in Dark Interstellar Matter of H(0) Decrease the Hope of Migrating to Exoplanets
If this is true, then the interstellar medium will be so dense and reactive that a vehicle that fast will require an extremely thick shield, like several kilometers thick. The vehicle I'm working on is about 20 to 30 kilometers in diameter, so that's 3 trillion tons of shielding, and the vehicle itself only weighs around 300 to 400 billion tons. The shielding it requires is just impossible to fit on the ship, so I went for another idea: using a very powerful photon rocket in reverse to blow away the particles. The blower engine will use the same technology as the main engine, this one, to fire an exawatt gamma ray beam.
But exactly how much energy is required to do that? Is it even possible? If the blower engine's power output is too high, then the recoil will be too much. The main engine can produce enough thrust to accelerate the vehicle at 0.01g, so it's a zettawatt class thruster that produces 3 to 4 billion tons of thrust, and I want to keep the blower thruster's power output less than 1/100 to 1/1000 times the power output of the main thruster.
EDIT:
The first article says that if ultra-dense hydrogen is dark matter, then it will make interstellar space much more densely packed with particles, like over 1e5 particles per cm³, and the relativistic impact with these ultra-dense hydrogen molecules will cause them to go nuclear. It results in the spaceship experiencing a 100kJ/cm² heating at 0.5c which will super-heat the hull to the temperature of a star and destroy the vehicle. So spaceships cannot go faster than very low relativistic speed, like 0.005c, without them getting heated up and destroyed.
The second article describes a GeV gamma ray photon rocked based on matter-antimatter annihilation. The engine mentioned doesn't have the heating and radiation issue that beam-core antimatter engines have.

You posted and deleted a similar question few hours ago. It's good norm to edit posted questions instead of doing what you just did.

Ok, I will not do that again.

And also pick one between science based and science fiction: as their wiki says, they are mutually exclusive

Ok, I will do that.

Lastly (in its current state I actually like this question, this is just a research pointer), viXra does have some good articles on it like the one you found, but it also has a lot of incoherent pseudoscience. This is in no way anything you did wrong, since you found an actually-okay source that has although still controversial seems alright from a conceptual standpoint, but I would warn against looking on viXra for actual research because of the volume of pseudoscience there. arXiv is basically the same site but is peer-reviewed so that you're much more likely to get good info.

if the medium is dense hydrogen, you could use the interstellar medium as fuel, aka bussard ramjet.

Where is it written that in Worldbuilding, any more than in any other fiction, the author is not allowed to ignore even real scientific facts, let alone broadly speculative articles?

I'd ignore Holmlid's claims about ultradense hydrogen Rydberg matter. A review article from 2022 starts:

The article by Holmlid and Zeiner-Gundersen (2019, Physica Scripta, vol. 94, 075005) contains a number of claims that explicitly or implicitly contradict fundamental knowledge of modern science. Some can only be true if long held conservation laws are broken. One such is baryon number conservation. A second fatal mistake is the treatment of the structure of molecules that disregard fundamental quantum mechanical aspects, such as the concept of kinetic energy operators and the Heisenberg indeterminacy relations.

It doesn't get any friendlier, either: these ideas are at least "disputed" and the explanations of why they're nonsensical make a lot of sense.
The interstellar medium isn't terribly helpful for relativistic flights, but the problem you're trying to solve almost certainly doesn't exist.

... and for a fiction project, it is more than reasonable to assume that the problem described in the question doesn't exist.

I strongly second that the mentioned article is not a source of valid information (I have not even read it, your summary was good enough for me). Until now the nature of dark matter or its behaviour or impact on spacefaring is not discovered to full extent. It is a theory still without any proof.
If you try to avoid a "logical mistake" of ignoring dark matter collisions in advance, you might end up accounting for something that is not true. So you end up with a "logical mistake" in your story... then why trying to avoid that situation in the first place?
Trying to use a laser to solve that "problem" is an interesting turn. But I have to admit, judging by the question's title, I was intrigued why you would not use some kind of shielding instead of a frontal beam only. Like an electo-magnetic field, generated all around the ship and strong enough to deccelerate any incoming particles to near stillstand or even repelling them. Of course this would require the particles being ionized or otherwise governable by electro-magnetical forces.
Then I realized: there is only this one defining requirement to dark matter, which is that it does not interact with anything but gravitational forces - hence "dark matter", because it does not emit or reflect light nor any other electro-magnetical radiation, we cannot see or directly detect it. Thus, a laser (and an electro-magnetical shield as well) would not do anything to dark matter anyways. (What happens if dark matter is able to absorb light/radiation to some extent, is another hypothetical question, though).
Even stronger, by definition of dark matter we cannot interact with it, except if we are able to generate gravitational "force fields of sorts" (even though gravitation is not ment to be a "force", accumulating lots of mass is a way to cause gravitational bending of spacetime). Then it is debatable if a "bumping into it" is a gravitational interaction or not (I'd say no).
I would argue, even if the name suggests being some kind of physical particle ("matter"), it is none. And if collision is not a gravitational force/interaction, we would just fly "through" it without even noticing it. If collission is supposed to be possible, then the theoretical/hypothetical effect would be that the mass would get heavier, but nothing else (nothing else because the theory ends there and describes nothing more; there would be no impact event, no explosions. Only the indirect effects of gravitation because of the increased mass would occur (bending spacetime). Bent spacetime might influence trajectories of moving mass near of it - and radiation like light as well).
In essence, dark matter is just a term coined to describe certain celestial effects ("wrong" rotational speeds of galaxies). There is no substance, no matter, behind it. I come to the conclusion: Dark matter does not matter. It only weighs in [pun intended] (and only if the theory can be confirmed one day) :D

This is 100% valid. Armor and blowers should be considered to avoid micrometeorites and dust (which at 0.3c are deadly) but dark matter, by definition, only interacts gravitationally as far as we know. If it doesn't, then it probably isn't "dark".

There's much more observational evidence related to "dark matter" than just the problem of rotational speed of galaxies.

Other answers point out that you can ignore some claims that make up your problem, but I'll focus on the interstellar gas blower. For some papers I've had to contemplate the effects of micrometeorite impacts on ultra-fast ships, and indeed appropriate armoring for the ship can become problematic. Even solar wind near stars (or interstellar gas particles far away), at sufficient speed, can strike the ship with such energy that they lead to considerable heating on large ships, which can be a problem because you can't easily radiate heat in space. This is discounting the fact that larger micrometeorites become problematic fast. At 30% of lightspeed, a one-nanogram micrometeorite hits with the force of almost a kilogram of TNT; one microgram, a ton of TNT, and one milligram, a kiloton of TNT. A tiny barely-detectable one-gram micrometeorite, which couldn't possibly be detected in time let alone evaded when moving at $0.3c$, would strike with the force of a large nuclear bomb.
So let's clear out the clutter with a laser.
If you're firing an exawatt laser, you need an energy source that can put out $10^{18}$ joules of energy per second (probably more; that figure assumes perfect laser efficiency). Needless to say, given that that power extended over any human-scale period of time is enough to instantly ionize virtually all materials,  it should be able to reduce anything that would damage the ship into (much finer) dust. If the region of space "in front" of the moving ship, i.e. the effective area of the laser, contains a billion tons of debris (probably far less), then that's equivalent to trying to sublimate a one-kilogram block of ice/dust with a megawatt laser. It would not be instantaneous, but it would certainly be effective.
Let's assume a black hole or antimatter reactor - something with perfect fuel efficiency: 100% mass-energy conversion of the fuel into electrical energy. This is also obviously an ideal case - the real figure will be probably much lower. Still, if we're working with 100% mass energy conversion, the ratio of energy output-to-fuel mass input is exactly $c^2$ - hence, $E=mc^2\iff\frac{E}{c^2}=m$. We can also then determine that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t},$$
so we know how much mass we're ejecting in the form of the laser's photons every second. As it turns out this value - $\frac{10^{18}}{c^2}$ - is only equivalent to about eleven kilograms of antimatter or black hole fuel per second.
We now know the mass flow rate out of the blower, and can simply calculate the thrust it produces as
$$F=\frac{1}{c}\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t}=c\frac{\mathrm{d}m}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$
That yields about 3.33 billion kilograms of thrust (3.33 million tons). If your craft weighs 400 billion tons, the acceleration that your main engine will need to counteract is about 0.00000834 meters per second per second - 8.34 micrometers per second per second. This is about $8.5\cdot10^{-7}$ gs of acceleration - given that your main engine produces acceleration a little more than four orders of magnitude greater at around $10^{-2}=0.01$ gs, your blower will have virtually no effect on your main engine.

Not to forget that the fuel still needs to be carried on the ship. 11kg of perfect fuel to fire the blower just one second adds up to high amounts depending on the intended time of flight and firing rate of the blower (supposed to be needed continuously). Probably the fuel is also very hard to produce in such quantities. But it is Sci-fi after all.
While your analysis is not focused on dark matter, I deem it very relevant to consider "normal" matter effects before "dark matter" effects. +1 from me.

@Antares Also consider that we're talking about a ship with a mass of over a billion tons propelled by a zettawatt engine. Finding the right fuel is comparatively trivial to building an engine, let alone a ship, of that scale. The civilization that builds this ship is expecting 0.3c speeds and billions of tons of payload; I think they've probably also figured out ultra-efficient fuel for their insanely-massive mega-starships, or at least they should have before they began construction...

You are right. I should have done the maths first. I thought it would also be in the magnitude of hundreds to thousands of billions of tons, but it is far lower. More like in the magnitude of one billion tons per lightyear of travel with continuous firing. The extra weight is negligable compared to the ship's dimensions.

FRAME CHALLENGE: have you considered using magnetic fields instead?
One of the original early proposals for interstellar travel was the Bussard Ramjet (see link below)
Bussard Ramjet
You probably already know about this idea this but bear with why I summarize - poorly) In short the idea was that a star ship equipped with magnetic field generators at its forward end would use a specifically 'shaped' set of magnetic field lines to divert molecular hydrogen from the interstellar medium  down into and through a 'scoop' at the front of the ship to fusion engines located at it's rear where the hydrogen would then act as the propellant in a sustained fusion reaction. This would take away the need to carry the thousands of tonnes of fuel needed for an interstellar voyage. The faster the ship was propelled the more distance it would cover and hence the more hydrogen gas it's magnetic fields would be exposed to.
While very elegant (on paper) a number of follow up studies identified problems with the idea. One of these problems is potentially relevant to your story.
And that was that one researcher calculated that the magnetic fields instead of funneling hydrogen towards the ship would tend to deflect it away from the vessel generating a decelerating force or drag in the process. So instead of sucking in air like a jet engine it acts more like an air breaks on an airliner.
SO I would suggest using using magnetic field lines in this way instead of lasers to clear the space in front of your ship.

Yes, but not ionized particles will not be deflected, since they are not charged.

@Victoria Genesis Then place  a plasma window/shield closer to the ship It would be a huge power hog given the likely diameter required but as per your description you have the power to spare.
